# SQL Server - Update whole row to null if duplicate

Tags: sql-server

I have this table in SQL Server 2008

```
+----------+----------+----------+
|    ID    |   Date   |   Desc   |
+----------+----------+----------+
|   I.001  |01/01/2014|   Test   |
|   I.001  |01/01/2014|   Test2  |
|   I.002  |02/01/2014|   Test3  |
|   I.002  |02/01/2014|   Test4  |
|   I.002  |02/01/2014|   Test5  |
+----------+----------+--------- +
```

and the table goes on with similar pattern. I am expecting a result like this

```
+----------+----------+----------+
|    ID    |   Date   |   Desc   |
+----------+----------+----------+
|   I.001  |01/01/2014|   Test   |
|   I.001  |   NULL   |   NULL   |
|   I.002  |02/01/2014|   Test3  |
|   I.002  |   NULL   |   NULL   |
|   I.002  |   NULL   |   NULL   |
+----------+----------+--------- +
```

Is there any SQL script allowing me to get the above result? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you check if the duplicate row is to be retained?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Duplicate here means having the same `ID` and `Date`. The row to be retained will be the one with first `DESC` alphabetically.

```
WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT *,
        RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID, [Date] ORDER BY [Desc])
    FROM YourTable
)
UPDATE Cte
    SET [Date] = NULL,
        [Desc] = NULL
WHERE RN > 1
```

Comment: Thanks. It works but somehow the rows have duplicated which originally was 19989 rows and now have become 39978 rows. Not sure if I type the query correctly.

    WITH Cte AS (SELECT     DocCode, DocDate, DES, 
    RN =    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DocCode, DocDate
                              ORDER BY DES)
    FROM         JournalDetail)
    UPDATE    Cte
     SET              DocDate = NULL, DES = NULL
     WHERE     RN > 1

Comment: What do you mean by duplicated?

Comment: @LiongLoong  `UPDATE` cannot increase the number of rows in your table.

Comment: There must be something in your application that inserts rows.

Comment: Ran the query again and this time works perfectly. Thanks @wewesthemenace.